# Scene seems to display four times larger when running simulator with retina dispay

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I am testing my app in the iphone simulator To test the retina display, I've set the hardware to iphone(retina)
Unfortunately, the entire scene seems to be scaled to four times its normal size! 
The only thing I see, is the left bottom quarter of the entire scene.
The app, since it exceeds the bounds of the screen, shows up only as a quarter on the iphone screen.
I am using Cocos2d. What is the cause of this? I also have retina display enabled in the app delegate. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator is increasing to four times it's normal size (twice on each axis) because by default it uses a 1:1 mapping of pixels.

In other words, one screen pixel = one device pixel.  So when you go to Retina display, which doubles the retina density, you need four times as much space to display the device screen.

Edit:

In response to the updated question, you can use the 'scale' feature.  Window->scale->50% (or command+3).

Comment: This strikes me as being the exactly correct answer. Not sure why the asker ignored it and reposted it just now.

Comment: Because he didn't like the answer?

Comment: Well, now there you go making the logical supposition :p

Comment: I apologize for not seeing the answer before and updating it. So, how should I go about to fix this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry to bother, but it occured to me that: isn't the scale feature a temporary fix? How exactly does the scale feature work? And is it applied onto the real retina display device? Thanks again!

Comment: The 'scale' feature basically says 'scrap the 1:1 mapping, and give me a screen reduced to 50% of the size 1:1 would give me'.  I don't know how it would work with 75%, but 50% probably just utilizes something similar to anti-aliasing to reduce 4 pixels to 1.  And it's PURELY a simulator setting; your code never knows anything about it (so it never hits a retina device...).

Comment: Thank you for all your help and all your responses! I think I understand now! And everything is working smoothly again! Again, thanks so much!!